# Ubuntu does not see keyboard and mouse

Tags: boot, hardware

I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS installed on my PC and WIndows 10 on other disk. Everytime I boot I select OS in Grub with keyboard. Yesterday the only thing I did outside /home was installing python 3.10 following [this](https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-python-versions-ubuntu-20-04/) guide and updating packages. And everything worked just fine. Today I am trying to login to ubuntu and both mouse and 2 keyboards (bluetooth and wired) just dont work. Everything works smoothly in Windows, Grub. I tried connecting devices to different usb ports but, obviously, that didn't work. I also tried recovery mode and updated grub, fixed broken packages (nothing was broken) and checked file system - everything is good. How do I fix this?
My PC has amd cpu and nvidia graphics card and msi motherboard, if thats necessary.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 system (Ubuntu releases using the *year* format are different to the far more common *year.month* system, ie. 20 is a *specialist flavor* of 20.04 that is *snap* package only intended to be used *headless*)  FYI:  If you change the default `python3` version on a *year.month* system, you'll lose all tools that rely on the default version that came with the system; worse is that some may still run but corruption can occur (ie. data loss) so be careful if using 20.04 or a *year.month* system over your stated 20 or *year* product system)

Comment: By Ubuntu 20 I mean Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I also tried entering terminal as root from recovery mode and noticed that ubuntu cannot connect to the internet. The default python is set to 3.8 which came with ubuntu installation

Comment: Please adjust your question then, as Ubuntu has used the *year* format (ie. 20) to represent the *specialist snap* only products that are different systems to common *year.month* products, and has done so since 2016.  20 is not 20.04 just like 18 was not 18.04, and 16 was not 16.04.